# What prevents this exploit from working (unix SUID)?

Tags: attacks, operating-systems, access-control, unix, file-system

If I have a user on a unix system where Im allowed to create new files, what prevents me from downloading an executable file onto that system which is already SUID'ed to root on a different system?

Scenario:

- I'm logged into a shell with my user Karrax (box1)
- On a different system (box2) where I'm already root I set SUID root on an executable
- I then transfer/copy the file over to box1

What prevents this file from running as root on the first shell I logged into?

Comment: This is documented in the chmod(1) man page.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When you copy a file to a different filesystem, what's going on under the hood is that a you create a new file and copy the contents. Moving a file to a different filesystem is done by copying then removing the source. So you have no more privileges when copying a file than at any other time you're creating a file.

When you create a file, it belongs to you. Many unix variants restrict changing the owner (`chown`) to root. Even those that allow the owner of a file to give it away clear the setuid and setgid bits when doing so. Group ownership changes (`chgrp`) also clear away the setxid bits unless invoked with root privileges. And you need to own the file or be root to change its permissions. So you can't create a setxid file for a user or group you don't have permission to run programs as.

A different vector for setxid file injection is filesystem mounting. Most configurations only allow the setxid bits on filesystems directly mounted by root (as opposed `/etc/fstab` entries with the `user` option on Linux, Samba, FUSE, …). Sometimes, for example with NFS mounts, it's up to the system administrator to ensure that filesystems are mounted with the `nosuid` option.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: please ignore my previous misguided answer, which I've edited out here to avoid confusing folks.  Gilles has a much better answer, which I could incorporate here or rephrase, but he deserves the credit....

If you really want to see what I had before, you can as always find it in the edit history by clicking on the time of edit.

Comment: Actually, you can set the SUID bit. You can't make it SUID to another user though, if you're not root.

Answer (score 3):

You get close to this behavior when you download someone's tarball and extract it, 'preserving ownership/permissions' if the uid is 7544 you will see that uid for the files you untar if you are root, likely errors if your a non privileged user.